# Configuring default compiler settings in Eclipse IDE for C/C++

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I am very new to Eclipse and I am currently running **Eclipse 2022-03** with **CDT 10.6.1** installed. I've been trying to setup the default C/C++ compiler flags for all projects but I do not understand how to.

I do know that configuring the compiler settings per project is possible through `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Settings Tab` in which many settings can be configured.

My question is, instead of doing it manually one by one for each new project,  **is it possible to configure the default compiler settings for all new C/C++ Managed Build projects?**

I have tried adding the compiler flags in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery Tab` and editing the command to get compiler specs but it seems to do nothing.

*As I side note, I create my projects using `New -> C/C++ Project` and choosing either the C or C++ Managed Build Template.*